# A part of code is not executing in c# Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When i am running this code i am getting the output

> "Snapshot Exsist 1"

. But anything after that is not working. I am not getting any error or any thing .
Y the following code are not working/ executing.

> ObjectToTurnOn.SetActive(true);

> ObjectToTurnOFF.SetActive(false);

> Debug.Log("Snapshot Exsist 2");

```
public void GetCompleteUserdata(string currUID){   
    Debug.Log("Going to get complete user data")
    DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("users").Document(currUID);
    
    docRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        if (snapshot.Exists) 
        {
            // DebugText.text = "Snapshot Exsist";
             Debug.Log("Snapshot Exsist 1");
             ObjectToTurnOn.SetActive(true);
             ObjectToTurnOFF.SetActive(false);  
             Debug.Log("Snapshot Exsist 2");
       
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting "Snapshot Exsist 1", twice, but it's only outputting this once.

From personal experience with Unity I'd say what's most likely happening is:

ObjectToTurnOn.SetActive(true);
ObjectToTurnOFF.SetActive(false);

, is the issue.

I don't know what object is ObjectToTurnOFF but if it's an object that this script is attached to, setting it inactive is going to stop the remainder of the script from running.

Comment: Please use code blocks and some formatting before submitting to make the answer more readable